# is it necessary to flatten cylindrical UVs when using an image texture?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

[image]

Im pretty new to UV unwrapping/mapping and Im planning on using stencils to paint decals onto the image texture. While everything else unwrapped pretty much square, im wondering if its necessary to flatten out the main body part of the UV (upper left in UV editor).

Comment: That depends on the image texture in question and how you intend to use it.  Some image textures are painted to match existing UV patterns, but most require some degree of straightening.

Comment: yes I think it will help... anyway it's pretty simple to use cylindrical projection, select just that part of your mesh, align your viewport -press numpad 3 in your case to see from right- and press U > Cylinder > Direction: View on Poles...

Comment: Cylinder projection will be more coherent, and it will be much easier to paint if you plan to do it in the Image Editor. If you plan to paint on the object into the 3D view you could simply choose Smart UV Project